# Is it acceptable practice to install an Authenticode code signing certificate directly on my build server to create a production signed build?

Tags: deployment, build, code-signing, tfsbuild, authenticode

Is it acceptable practice to install an Authenticode code signing certificate directly on a build server to create a production signed build?  I’m looking for some resources on the net that suggest or support that this practice is legitimate providing you’ve taken appropriate steps to secure the build server and the process by which a build is created and deployed.

All the “best practice” guidance I can find about code signing practices are way over the top in terms of suggested process.  Microsoft’s reference document has as many as 6 servers in play for the simple act of signing a single assembly.  http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/7/af7777e5-7dcd-4800-8a0a-b18336565f5b/best_practices.doc

## Some background:

My company creates simple rich-client line of business applications for its employees and direct customers.  We do not create commercial software.  My build server is physically secured and network secured using my companies strict security policies and procedures.  Only very specific people in the organization have the ability to even start a build in my environment.

Our current process requires me to break a build/deploy process into many stages with **a lot** of manual process in place.  We use physical devices to store the Authenticode certificates, requiring user-entered PINs to access.  We have to shuffle the assemblies/manifests that require code signing to designated code signing PCs which also have to be physically secured.

To me, it is less secure to pass around a physical token/device and leave all these manual steps in place.   There is nothing stopping a person with physical access to the token/device from signing anything they want.  At least, with an automated, logged, controlled build server environment, you know what was signed and by who.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with installing a certificate on a build server and making it accessible to a build account, is that now any developer can sign any malicious piece of code by temporarily commiting it to some legitimate project, and reverting it back after the build.

No matter the actions are logged, the breach is hard to identify or prevent. Especially if development is active and several builds are done per day.

The only solution I can think of is to limit a number of people who can trigger an "RTM" build. Other build types may use a test certificate or avoid signing at all.

In fact, this is the question I bother my head too.

Comment: [Recent leakage](http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2012/09/adobe-to-revoke-code-signing-certificate.html) of Adobe's code signing certificate from a breached build server raises even more doubts.

Comment: Actually, [Adobe's current description](http://blogs.adobe.com/asset/2012/09/inappropriate-use-of-adobe-code-signing-certificate.html) of their own issue specifically says that their build server did not have access to the private key info.  Stating: "The compromised build server did not have rights to any public key infrastructure (PKI) functions other than the ability to make code signing requests to the code signing service."

I'm not sure this casts any more doubt on my inquiry.  It is all a shell game of Risk vs. Reward.  Thankfully for me, I think of myself as a low-value target.

Comment: Yes, the certificate was not stolen. But the story shows that one doesn't need to bother stealing it when the build server offers the same service in unattended mode. And is less secure than any HSM.